# Python Memory leak in pyautogui, unsure the cause

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have a memory leak in my pyautogui script I made. I have no idea where it's coming from or what might be causing it.

The script is made to perfectly press space for a skill check in a game. So it just checks for when a pixel (out of an array) turns white and then changes color indicating the skill check bar has passed over it.

I don't feel like I'm doing anything unusual here that would cause a memory leak, it wouldn't be on the pyautogui side would it?

```
import pyautogui as auto
import keyboard
import random
import time
import random

circleLocations = [(1023, 522), (1025, 527), (1025, 537), (1024, 548), (1022, 560), (1018, 568)]  

def delay(value1 = 0.05, value2 = 0.2):
    return random.uniform(value1,value2)

def perfectSpacePress(x, y):
    while auto.pixelMatchesColor(x, y, (255,255,255)):
        print("waiting")
    time.sleep(delay(0.1,0.15 ))
    auto.press(' ')
    print("PressedCircleSpace")

def checkCircle():
    for location in circleLocations:
        if auto.pixelMatchesColor(location[0], location[1], (255,255,255)):
            perfectSpacePress(location[0], location[1])

try:
    while True:
        checkCircle()
        time.sleep(0.1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:     
    print('\nDone.')
```